# Remove all .gitignore files of my folder

Tags: git, unix, github, command

Is there a way for finding and deleting all .gitignore files ?

I must delete them before upload my project folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

on linux / mac os execute the folling command in your terminal:

```
find . -type f -name .gitignore -exec rm {} \;
```

this finds all files of type file with the name .gitignore and deletes them.

Comment: Thank you. A quick question. I got no output in the terminal. So that means that there is no more .gitignore files in my directory, right?

Comment: yes. If you have the problem again, your can add -print option to find, it will print the paths it found before it deletes them

Answer (score 5):

Also you can do it with standard git methods, see git clean [man](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) and -X option.

Comment: I think there's ambiguity in the question. The selected answer deletes the actual `.gitignore` files while your answers deleted the files that are listed by name in the `.gitignore` files.